# Finding The Area Of A Triangle

Tags: java

I have a question that I would like to ask you. In my book for java programming, it asks me to write a program that finds the area of a triangle given 3 points. I tried many ways but I could never get the right answer. Can you please give me a solution to this problem. Thanks! Here is the question:

[image: 2.15]

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class shw2point15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three points for a triangle:");

        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();
        double x3 = input.nextDouble();
        double y3 = input.nextDouble();


        double s = ((x1 + y1) + (x2 + y2) + (x3 + y3)) / 2;
        double area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - (x1 - y1)) * (s - (x2 - y2)) * (s - (x3 - y3)));



        System.out.println("The area of the triangle is " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you are adding x1 to y1, to find the length of a side, I think it is done a different way, but I failed geometry so I cannot help

Comment: Is this you? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/329771/finding-area-of-a-triangle-using-equations

Comment: *3* points; 6 numbers. I was a bit puzzled by that.

Comment: Triangle with 6 points? Wouldn't a triangle just need 3 *points*?

Comment: I do not think this is a SO question, look it up on a math website.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516219/finding-out-the-area-of-a-triangle-if-the-coordinates-of-the-three-vertices-are

Comment: I would have thought that `side1 = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`, unless I've misunderstood what is meant by "side". (Note: I'm using latex-y notation there, not Java notation, i.e. `^` means power, not bitwise XOR).

Comment: @Andreas triangle has 3 vertices, with two coordinates each, so it's 6 numbers.

Comment: @Yakuza I know, but question says *"triangle given 6 **points**"*

Comment: Here is what you need http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/trigonometry/triangle_given_3_points.htm

Comment: @Andreas since the question image says "three points", I've edited the question.

Comment: This seems like a very complicated way of doing it, rather than just using half the length of the cross product: `abs(((x2-x1)*(y3-y1) - (y2-y1)*(x3-x1))/2)`.

Comment: the triangle is on a line graph, so each point would have an X and Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a correct answer is because you are not finding the sides correctly. However, after finding the side length you can get the answer. Here is what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three points for a triangle:");

        //Store the values in an array.
        double[] xCoordinates = new double[3];
        double[] yCoordinates = new double[3];
        double[] sides = new double[3];

//      Input the values into the array
        xCoordinates[0] = input.nextDouble();
        yCoordinates[0] = input.nextDouble();
        xCoordinates[1] = input.nextDouble();
        yCoordinates[1] = input.nextDouble();
        xCoordinates[2] = input.nextDouble();
        yCoordinates[2] = input.nextDouble();

//      Find the side length from the input. There probably are better ways to do this.
        sides[0] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xCoordinates[0]-xCoordinates[1], 2)+Math.pow(yCoordinates[0]-yCoordinates[1], 2));
        sides[1] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xCoordinates[1]-xCoordinates[2], 2)+Math.pow(yCoordinates[1]-yCoordinates[2], 2));
        sides[2] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xCoordinates[2]-xCoordinates[0], 2)+Math.pow(yCoordinates[2]-yCoordinates[0], 2));

//      Find s from the sides
        double s = ( sides[0]+sides[1]+sides[2] )/2;

//      Find the area.
        double area = Math.sqrt(s*( s-sides[0] )*( s-sides[1] )*( s-sides[2] ));

//      Print the area
        System.out.println("The area of the triangle is "+area);

//      Output~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Enter three points for a triangle:
//      1.5
//      -3.4
//      4.6
//      5
//      9.5
//      -3.4
//      The area of the triangle is 33.600000000000016
}'
```